# How can I have a callback on stdout/stderr readiness instead of busy polling?

Tags: java, android, process, io

All the discussions I found of reading from `Process` stdout do it in a blocking way, like here:

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
for(String line;(line=in.readLine())!=null;)
{
    useText(line);
}
```

If I try to avoid blocking, my option is to poll the stream using `in.ready()`.

But what I really need is to leave the process running and do something useful, and only try to read anything when the data is actually available. So I'm looking for something like Qt's `QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput` signal. Note that `BufferedReader`'s nethod `ready` is not what I'm looking for: it's simply a method I would have to repeatedly check, rather than any sort of signal.

Is there anything like that in Java?

Comment: If you want to do two things at once, the simplest solution is to use two threads. One thread reads from the output of the program, and the other thread does whatever you need to do at the same time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sure, but that adds complexity (synchronization etc.).

Comment: You aren't polling with this code. You are doing blocking I/O.

Comment: @user207421 right, and if I try to avoid blocking, I'd resort to polling using `in.ready()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an event loop, you can start a background thread to add events to that event loop.

e.g.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // capture errors as well.
Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
            Activity.runOnUiThread(() -> useText(line));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(e);
    } finally {
        Activity.runOnUiThread(() -> noMoreText());
    }
});
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

---

You can have a thread which only does `queue.add(in.readLine())` then your main thread can poll this queue. That way all multi-threading issues are simple and contained.

```
static final String EOF = new String(); // use for == comparison later

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // capture errors as well.
Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
int capacity = 1024;
BlockingQueue<String> lines = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(capacity);
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
            lines.add(line);
            while (lines.remainingCapacity() < 2) // don't run out of memory if too much.
                Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(e);
    } finally {
        lines.offer(EOF);
    }
});
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();

// later in a loop
String line = lines.poll();
if (line == null) // no data yet.

else if (line == EOF) // we have the EOF marker.
```

Comment: So, we arrive at busy polling again. How is this approach with `lines.poll()` better than `in.ready()` (assuming that the process always prints whole lines)?

Comment: @Ruslan You appear to be looking for a threading model where you respond to callbacks once an event is triggered. In Java, this is achieved by having background threads add jobs to an event loop.  Unless you have an event loop, this isn't going to work. Is this for a GUI? If so you can use `SwingUtils.invokeLater`

Comment: This is an Android GUI app, so I suppose there's some event loop hidden. Sorry for failing to mention this in the OP.

Comment: @Ruslan I have added an example which assumes you have an Android event loop.

Comment: Hmm, Android doesn't have Swing, does it? (I'm about the `finally` part of your example). I suppose you mean `Activity.runOnUiThread` there too instead of `SwingUtils.invokeLater`.